# adding elements of one array to another at a particular place in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
byte[] array1=new byte[]{0x01,0x05};
byte[] array2=new byte[]{0x03,0x04,0x02};
```

I want to add `array2` in between `array1[0]` and `array1[1]`.I do not want to delete any values from `array1` after adding `array2`.Whatever may be the values in array2,it should be added to array1 as it is.I am not expecting the sorted order.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "add array2 in the array1[0] and array1[1]"?

Comment: finally i want array1 to be as {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05}

Comment: @sup so it should be sorted?

Comment: what ever may be the values i want them to add array2 in between array1[0] and array1[1]. in this case in the sorted order.

Comment: sorry not the sorted order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third array to accomplish this.

```
    byte[] array1=new byte[]{0x01,0x05};
    byte[] array2=new byte[]{0x03,0x04,0x02};
    byte[] targetArray = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, targetArray, 0, array1.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, targetArray, array1.length, array2.length);

    for (byte b : targetArray) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

result:

```
1
5
3
4
2
```

Alternative to put `array2` in between `array1`s values

```
    byte[] array1=new byte[]{0x01,0x05};
    byte[] array2=new byte[]{0x03,0x04,0x02};
    byte[] targetArray = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];
    int cap = array1.length / 2;

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, targetArray, 0, cap);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, targetArray, cap, array2.length);
    System.arraycopy(array1, cap, targetArray, array2.length + cap, array1.length - cap);

    for (byte b : targetArray) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Result:

```
1
3
4
2
5
```

Comment: if the second array is {0x03,0x02,0x04}, how will i add that,i do not want them to be in the sorted order.i want the answer to be{0x01,0x03,0x02,0x04,0x05}

Comment: Remove the `Arrays.sort()` and you're fine. The values will be added to the target array in the order they come from the source arrays.

Comment: i tried that but the output is displayed as 1 5 2 3 4

Comment: im not expecting the sorted order . whatever may be values in array2 should be between array1[0] and array1[1].

Comment: Did you change `array2`s values or their order? In this code they're already sorted, so the output is sorted as well.

Comment: i have edit my question and changed array2,please help me in that case

Comment: i am expecting the result to be as 1 3 4 2 5.

Comment: i tried changing this line System.arraycopy(array2, 0, targetArray, array1.length-1, array2.length);. then im getting the output as 1 3 4 2 0

Comment: The result with this method will be all values of `array1` in the order they come followed by the values of `array2` in the order they come. I don't know how a result of 1 3 4 2 5 can be expected. Do you want to put `array2` between `array1`s values?

Comment: ya exactly.i am expecting to put array2 values in between array1's value

Comment: edited with alternative solution to match your request

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new array which is of size `array1.length + array2.length` and then using something like [`System.arrayCopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to throw in your current arrays in the order you need them to be,

Comment: how to add to a particular index

Comment: i have tried this for adding to starting and end of the array . but how to add  in the middle

Comment: @sup: The method linked in my answer specifies 2 index values. These will determine from where you start copying from the source array and to where you'll begin writing to the destination array.

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns a new array that containing the data from **insertIn** to index **position**, then all data from **toInsert** and then the rest of **insertIn** (This code is not fully tested, please implement a unit test for that method ;-) )

```
import static java.lang.System.arraycopy;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] array1 = new byte[] {0x01, 0x05 };
        byte[] array2 = new byte[] {0x03, 0x04, 0x02 };

        // add array 2 in array 1 at index 1
        byte[] inserted = insertIn(array1, array2, 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inserted));
    }

    public static byte[] insertIn(byte[] insertIn, byte[] toInsert, int position) {
        assert position > 0 && position <= insertIn.length;

        byte[] result = new byte[insertIn.length + toInsert.length];
        // copy start of insertIn
        arraycopy(insertIn, 0, result, 0, position);
        // copy toInsert
        arraycopy(toInsert, 0, result, position, toInsert.length);
        // copy rest of insertIn
        int restIndexInResult = position + toInsert.length;
        int restLength = toInsert.length - position - 1;
        arraycopy(insertIn, position, result, restIndexInResult , restLength);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Result: [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]

Comment: you mean how to use it?

Comment: ya exactly i want to know that

Comment: I changed the answer to full usage

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution can be the following:

```
    byte[] array1=new byte[]{0x01,0x05};
    byte[] array2=new byte[]{0x02,0x03,0x04};

    byte[] newArray = new byte[array1.length+array2.length];
    newArray[0]=array1[0];
    for(int i=1; i<newArray.length; i++){
        if(i<=array2.length){
            newArray[i]=array2[i-1];
        }else{
            newArray[i]=array1[i-3];
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to combile both array, you have to create third array which will hold both arrays data:

```
    byte[] array1=new byte[]{0x01,0x05};
    byte[] array2=new byte[]{0x02,0x03,0x04};

    int array1Len = array1.length;
    int array2Len = array2.length;
    byte[] array3 = new byte[array1Len+array2Len];

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array3, 0, array1Len);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array3, array1Len, array2Len);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the method using systemarraycopy which accepts the two arrays and positon where the second array you want insert in the first array

```
public static byte[] append(byte[] a, byte[] b,int position) {
byte[] c= new byte[a.length+b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, position);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, position, b.length);
System.arraycopy(a, position , c, position + b.length , a.length - position);
return c; }
```